# Conditional sum with NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sum

I have a following dataframe.

| id | color | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | green | B |
| 2 | red |  |
| 3 |  | C |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 | blue | A |

I have to add columns named `col_scr` and `grd_scr` based on color and grade. Then I have to add those two columns to get a column named `final_score`. My desired dataframe should look like as follow,

| id | color | grade | col_scr | grd_scr | final_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | green | B | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | red |  | 3 | NA | 3 |
| 3 |  | C | NA | 0 | 0 |
| 4 |  |  | NA | NA | NA |
| 5 | blue | A | 2 | 2 | 4 |

My code so far looks like,

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(col_scr = case_when(color == 'green' ~ 1,
                              color == 'blue' ~ 2,
                              color == 'red' ~ 3),
          grd_scr = case_when(grade == 'A' ~ 2,
                              grade == 'B' ~ 1,
                              grade == 'C' ~ 0))
```

How to add my 3rd column `final_score` into `mutate`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data set using `dput`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `ifelse` condition to sum only if both variable are not NAs,  otherwise NA (credits to @Darren Tsai for the `if_all` part).

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(final_score = ifelse(if_all(col_csr:grd_scr, is.na), 
                              NA, rowSums(across(col_scr:grd_scr), na.rm = T)))
```

Comment: @Maël your code gives 2 for all rows in the final_score column

Comment: @learner See my edit, it should work fine now.